# Rails Updating a associated Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reference, model

I have the following:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end
```

I have no trouble creating new tasks for a person, but it gets hard when trying to update a taks.

At the begining I had a partial for both actions:

```
<%= form_for([@person, @person.tasks.build]) do |f| %>
    # Form stuff
    <%= f.submit "Guardar", :class => 'btn'%>
<% end %>
```

but it kept creating new objects when trying to update. So I created separated forms for create and update, and the second one is something like this:

```
<%= form_for([@person, @task], :url => {:action => :update} ) do |f| %>
    # Form stuff
    <%= f.submit "Guardar", :class => 'btn'%>
<% end %>
```

My question is, Is there a way of doing both things with only one form? How does it knows when to create or update when using a single model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. They are called nested attributes. This rails cast goes over the basics of how to implement nested attributes in your application:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Comment: But I don't want to update both models at the same time, I just want to update a task and I can't use the usual:
`<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
    # Form stuff
    <%= f.submit "Guardar", :class => 'btn'%>
<% end %>` because it throws some routing errors (that is logic since it belongs to another model)

Comment: It shouldn't throw errors. The errors are usually routing errors, e.g. no such method task_path(@task). Instead of url: {action: :update}, can you try: `url: person_task_path(@person, @task)`?

Comment: That works for both cases, so i just used form_for([@person, @task]), thanks =D. So, what's the difference with form_for([@person, @person.tasks.build])

Comment: `@person.task.build` instantiates a new task with `user_id: @person.id`, whereas `@task` uses an already instantiated object.